# What are the best methods and algorithms available in Machine Learning for automatically detecting and extracting EVENTS from E-mails

Tags: machine-learning

Can Someone tell me about the available algorithms in machine learning and which is the best one to extract events from email,please provide suitable links also...thanks in advance :D

Comment: what do you mean by "events"--e.g., an item that could be placed on a calendar (occurring at a specific date/time)?

Comment: yeah event means some sort of deadline,festival,seminar etc... i want it in this format not necessarily                                         Event Name :                                                             Date       :                                                           Location   :           thats it :D

Answer (score 2):

Use NLP grammar tools for that purpose i.e [GATE/JAPE](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/thakker-jape-tutorial/GATE%20JAPE%20manual.pdf) or [GExp](http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/). You can find calendar event parser for russian based on Gexp [here](http://g-calendar.appspot.com/application/testmessage)

Comment: Yeah thanks but i am trying to design such kind of a tool so i need to know the algorithms used in those tools i would be grateful if you can help me out...

Comment: Actually, GExp is my project so yes I know how to design such tools. Algorithms behinds them is Regular Expression engine with some domain depended operators(such as match inside, match by predicate). How to design simple Regular Expression engine you can anywhere on the web.

Comment: It is more about Natural Langauge Processing(NLP) which is include ML. In this situation grammar engine are more appropriate way to solve problem. and generation of GRAMMAR using ML next very hard step.